# About the position of the object clause

Tags: grammar, adverbs

1.Which of the sentences below is best, and why?

> People are saying that this is great about X (for example: our new product).
>   People are saying about X that this is great.
>   People are saying great about X.

2.Is the 'about X' phrase an adverb phrase?

Comment: None of these seem quite right; probably because *this* is being used without context to establish what *this* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"People are saying that this is one of the great things about X." is more appropriate than any of the suggestions you gave.